# set path in aquamacs

Tags: emacs, latex, aquamacs

I recently switched computers and can't figure out how I was able to get auctex to search the correct path to find my template tex files (for use with \input{}).  I thought that aquamacs uses the $PATH from bash_profile or bashrc but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [auctex-config.el](http://braeburn.aquamacs.org/code/master/aquamacs/src/site-lisp/auctex-config.el).  You might have to edit it to set correct paths to texbin and other binaries that are necessary.  If you already have this auctex-config.el, you might need to edit it to set the paths correctly.